# Swift UIButton background image not being set by UIImagePicker

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I am able to select an Image from the PhotoLibrary but the background image of my UIButton does not change. The println in didFinishPickingImage and imagePickerControllerDidCancel does not show in the console so I do not think those functions are being called.

```
class AddTeamTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
var picker:UIImagePickerController? = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet var teamNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var schoolName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var teamImage: UIButton!
@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func addTeam(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newTeam = Team()
    var onlineTeam = PFObject(className: "Team")
    // add new team to the list
    newTeam.name = teamNumber.text
    newTeam.schoolName = schoolName.text
    teamList.append(newTeam)
    // add online
    onlineTeam["name"] = newTeam.name
    onlineTeam["fromUser"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    onlineTeam["schoolName"] = newTeam.schoolName
    onlineTeam.save()
    //close the view
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}
@IBAction func pickImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    var alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    var cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openCamera()
    }
    var galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openGallery()
    }       
    var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
    }
    alert.addAction(cameraAction)
    alert.addAction(galleryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    /*
    alert.delegate = self
    alert.message = "Choose Image Source"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Camera")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Photo Library")
    alert.show()
    */
    //image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    //image.allowsEditing = false
    //self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func openCamera() {
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        openGallery()
    }
}
func openGallery() {
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    println("Image selected")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    teamImage.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {
    println("picker cancel")
}
}
```

Comment: when you set the the contents and size of the button before setting the image ?

Answer (score 1):

The button doesn't seem initialized

```
let teamImage: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 380, height: 300))
let imageTest = UIImage(named: "Hypnotoad")

teamImage.setTitle("HypnotoadTitle", forState: .Normal)
teamImage.setBackgroundImage(imageTest, forState: .Normal)
```

tested this in a Playground and works ok.

[image: Playground test of UIButton with backgroundImage]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and advice.  I had set the button size and initial background image in the Main.storyboard, but I did try what you suggested and used the programatic code you had used.  But no, I am able to set the background image if I set the image, but I am wanting the user to be able to choose the image file from their photo library or camera, and it is not changing to the image the user chooses.

Comment: Try to set the delegate of the "UIImagePickerController". In your code in "openGallery" set `picker?.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had 2 different variables of type UIImagePickerController and I was saving to the wrong one.  I deleted the first var picker declaration and combined the code to just one UIImagePickerController and it works as intended.